# Past perfect vs Present perfect

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

Both sentences are in the past, what is the difference?

Mr X had driven them home.

Mr X has driven them home.

Answer (score 0):

the difference is that the first sentence is in past perfect because the auxiliary you are using is had, while the second sentence is written in present perfect for this time we use as auxiliary Has / Have.
Another big difference is the usefulness of these times.

The Present Perfect we use it when.
An action that started in the past and continues to the present.
I have lived in this city for six months.
An action that happened before now (unspecified time)

While the Past Perfect we use it when:
An action that happened before a time in the past

Comment: So on the example above I should use the past perfect  instead of the present perfect. Mr X had driven them home.  Driving someone´s home is an action that comes with an ending. While in your example I have lived in this city for 6 months implies a continuity... Is this correct? Thank you!